# Doctrine migration is not respecting entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-migration

I made a new entity in symfony

```
...
class MenuDay
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\MenuWeek", inversedBy="menuDays")
     */
    private $menuWeek;
...
```

and when i try to make:migration it only generate table with no column

```
...
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'sqlite', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'sqlite\'.');

    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE menu_day (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL)');
}
...
```

it looks like error, but i don't know what I'm doing wrong. Also I want to avoid manually hardcode those new columns into migration file. It is my first project with this type of error. 
If you need some additional information, I'll edit this post.

I'm bit in panic mode. Please help me, you are my only hope. :) Thank you!

Comment: Could you try `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to check if you have the same result

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another migration with the ALTER statements. Existing migrations are not updated.

Comment: Guys thank you, but it looks like this whole symfony instance was somehow corrupted, it started making a lot more random errors. It was 4.3. 
I installed fresh new version 5.0 and now I'm copying old code to new installation, and it works fine